# Input source for Logitech 750 keyboard not working as expected

Tags: keyboard

I have a Logitech 750 and until now I have been able to properly use it as my keyboard in my Macbook (same layout).

All of sudden (or at least I don't know what I have changed), for the key that I was able to type a back tick (`), now I can type this: §.

In my input source, I have US selected and I see this:

[image]

How can I use the backtick where § is located?

The physical layout of my Logitech 750 is this one:

[image]

Comment: That's the correct location for an ISO [International] keyboard. ANSI [US] keyboards don't have the key left of z so have to move the ` to left of 1. Precisely what layout is your physical keyboard? See https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201794 for some different international keyboards.

Comment: @Tetsujin I've added the physical layout in the body of the question itself.

Comment: Ah, so it is an ANSI - seems the Mac has 'forgotten' what type it is. Try the Bluetooth setup, you need to persuade it to ask you to "Press the key Left of Z" - that's how it figures out what keyboard type it is.

Comment: Also see https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/specify-a-keyboard-type-mchlp2886/10.14/mac/10.14

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/255082/ https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/292928/ Is your blog (mentioned in first link) still active? On an unrelated note, you have an unregistered profile too, which you visited '13 last; you can request a merger.

Comment: Thank yalls - manually setting keyboard type worked!. @ankii which blog you talking about?

Comment: Please post an answer Nobita :) Oh I missed tagging @TomGewecke in my last comment who has a blog over this topic it seems.