# How to make ' and < map to the right keys (force change from ANSI to ISO)?

Tags: keyboard, internationalization, plist, iso

My separate keyboard (a Das Keyboard 4 Ultimate with [ISO layout](https://support.apple.com/en-sa/HT201794)) has, to my chagrin, a different and erroneous keyboard mapping than the MacBook's built-in (also ISO).

The biggest annoyance is the different mapping of the `'` and `<` keys.

The built in laptop keyboard is like so (Norwegian locale, ISO layout):

[image]

While the separate keyboard behaves like so (ANSI layout):

[image]

This is not the correct layout. E.g. the Enter/Return button is wrong (1 row). It should be like this (again ISO layout):

[image]

Note that the Enter/Return button is 2 rows high here.

Unfortunately, the Mac setup does not fully recognise the keyboard:

[image]

… even though it lists it in System preferences, under Modifier keys:

[image]

Changing between ISO and ANSI does not help:

[image]

Note that the Ultimate keyboard is completely blank:

[image]

Finally, on the Keyboard Setup Assistant intro screen, it is stated *“Your **Logitech** device cannot be identified and will not be usable until it is identified”* (Emphasis mine). While I have a Logitech mouse, the keyboard is, as described, from another manufacturer. I have never attached a Logitech keyboard to the computer.

[image]

I have tried to search for answers here on Stack Exchange. I have found similar topics [like this](https://superuser.com/q/334397/287154), [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/304819/57188) and [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/255082/external-iso-keyboards-treated-as-ansi-since-macbook-pro-upgraded-to-macos-sierr), but none that answers this issue.

Comment: Ah, OK. I see it now.

Answer (score 3):

After removing the `com.apple.keyboardtype.plist` file (found in `/Library/Preferences/`) and restarting, the Mac stopped referencing the non-existent Logitech keyboard. I could now use the Keyboard Setup Assistant, and finally the ISO layout was respected, solving the problem.

[image]

FWIW, this is the binary content of the plist I ended up with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>keyboardtype</key>
    <dict>
        <key>320-9456-0</key>
        <integer>41</integer>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 2):

If deleting the plist files doesn't work (it didn't to me) I have found in some answer to [old similar question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/255826/497475) that after reseting to default the shortcuts this issue may be fixed:

System Settings -> Keyboard -> Keyboard Shortcuts -> Restore defaults

(And reboot)